# TNS error while connecting to an Oracle DB running as ACI through an Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, oracle, azure-networking, azure-application-gateway, azure-container-service

I have an Oracel DB runnning as an Azure Container Instance.
To connect to the container, I set up an Azure Applicaiton Gateway as described here: [Expose a static IP address for a container group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-application-gateway)

Now I can reach the DB via az cli (tnsping & sqlplus login), but not from my client. When I try to tnsping the container through the public IP, I get a TNS packet checksum failure, and I can not get behind why.

From my client I get a successful ping of the public IP ("11.222.333.44"), as well as an open port 1521 with nmap.

But, the tnsping returns: `TNS-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure`

```
tnsping myDB
Attempting to contact(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 11.222.333.44)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = abc)))
TNS-12569: TNS:packet checksum failure
```

And an sqlplus login attempt returns: `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`

Other anomalies that might be symptoms of the issue I have encountered in Azure:

- In the ACI Overview: IP address stays private (does not display the public IP associated with it). This is also true for a dummy setup (container, gateway, IP) I created with the hello world container image and port 80, but differs from [this video I checked](https://youtu.be/WaA5P27IxU4) , which describes the same process as the MS learn article shared above.
- The Application Gateway attests the backend pool of the ACI as unhealthy due to blocked diagnostic ports.I was not able to resolve this with the Troubleshoot action or the linked MS help article.  The Error message  in Application gatewayas / Backend health reads as follows:

> The backend health status could not be retrieved. This happens when an NSG/UDR/Firewall on the application gateway subnet is blocking traffic on ports 65503-65534 in case of v1 SKU, and ports 65200-65535 in case of the v2 SKU or if the FQDN configured in the backend pool could not be resolved to an IP address. To learn more visit - [https://aka.ms/UnknownBackendHealth."](https://aka.ms/UnknownBackendHealth.%22)

Comment: Remove sensitive information from question such as public ip, connection strings etc.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up, I already use dummy information in the question. (11.222.333.44 is not my actual public IP)